# How to search for unknown path with Mongodb in object with an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

We have a system at my work where we storage information in a json type field, we currently use mysql. One of our newest needs, is to search for information that matches a criteria in the json field, but the issue with that field, is that the path to search for information is unknown, so we have to perform a deep search (not sure if this what it's called).

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(answers, 'one', '%search_criteria%') FROM table 
WHERE id = x
```

This works, but as we have to search the whole field (and it can be really big), it's really slow, and we want to see if this can be improved with mongodb.

The field has somewhat of a consistent format, but the path is unknown, we have something like this:

```
[{
  "id": 61,
  "questions": {
    "variables": [
      {
        'type_id': 50,
        'label': 'Bye world',
        'answer': false,

      },
      {
        'type_id': 15,
        'label': 'Blah blah',
        'answer': 'Bleh',

      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": 62,
  "questions": {
    "variables": [
      {
        'type_id': 56,
        'label': 'comment',
        'answer': 'Nice comment!',

      },
      {
        'type_id': 15,
        'label': 'Blah blah',
        'answer': 'Bleh',

      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": 63,
  "questions": {
    "variables": [
      {
        'type_id': 15,
        'label': 'Blah blah',
        'answer': 'Bleh!',

      },
      {
        'type_id': 56,
        'label': 'Another comment',
        'answer': 'Bad comment!',

      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

In the json field, we are going to look for the type_id, and maybe for the text in the label, but at the moment, for the type id, sometimes it will be present, some other don't, and it won't be in the same position, so I'm not sure on how to perform the search.

I never use mongobd before, so I don't know if I'm close to the answer, but I have tried this:

```js
db.getCollection('collection').find({
  answers : {'0.questions.0.variables.0.type_id' : 56 }
})
```

I know in the last example I'm trying to search in an specific path, but I was trying at least that first.

I have also looked https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/ but I don't know if this applies for this.

In the end, we want to get all matching results, in this case, all the answers that have type_id = 56 in their variables.

Comment: My bad, json fixed.

Comment: I think it is, the real example has much more data, but the path to an answer is the same, I did try to get the data with `answers: { 'questions.variables.type_id' : 56 }` but I didn't get any result back.

Comment: Not sure why you add the `answers` there ... your find looks exactly like this: `db.<YourCollectionName>.find({"questions.variables.type_id": 56})` See it working here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_MIK5MSA7LB

Comment: Well, I'm using a collection that contains an answer object with the json that I provided, and as we are planning to just move that field to mongo, I wrote my question that way, but with my current data, we have more objects, thats why I'm adding the "answers", I assumed that with the information I provided it will be enough, but for the example that I provided, your answer works.

Comment: So if you have a parent `answers` then you query would simply be: `db.<YourCollectionName>.find({"answers.questions.variables.type_id": 56})`

Comment: The answers object should be an array or something else? Currently is a string (It's a csv import from a mysql table), because I'm running the query and I don't see any information after executing the query, if that's the case, I will create a new collection with just the information provided.

Comment: I changed the data type in my collection, and the query worked as you said @Akrion, thanks for the help !!